# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - python dictionary attribute

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset

Good Morning
I am new to Data Science, I am doing data exploration, I created a dictionary (tax), when I am going to assign the (tax) created in my DF, it gives a syntax error.

```
df['TAX_PRESENT'] = [tax[resp] for resp in df.TAX CLASS AT PRESENT]

  File "<ipython-input-283-f131f0d2d00f>", line 1
    df['TAX_PRESENT'] = [tax[resp] for resp in df.TAX CLASS AT PRESENT]
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `CLASS AT PRESENT`? That isn't valid syntax. Is that supposed to be `df.TAX_CLASS_AT_PRESENT`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to connect the name of the column with underscore:

```
df['TAX_PRESENT'] = [tax[resp] for resp in df.TAX_CLASS_AT_PRESENT]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped a lot.